# Why is extruding a bezier curve making these loops?

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

After extruding one time or subdividing the curve, if I try to extrude again, I get a figure 8 loop. I've used bezier curves before, but this is the first time in 2.9. Anyone know how to work around this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of extrusion actually splits this control point and adds a new one in the middle.

[image]

It's not obvious that it happens since they are in the same location.

Comment: Wooowwww I didn't know what you meant at first, but after clicking around I see it. WTH? Maybe I'm just a noob, but I don't think that's not very intuitive.

Comment: if you want a branch I think you can duplicate a control point and right click to send it back to original position, then you can extrude it basically starting a new curve